# Order of an element and its inverse in a group

Tags: group-theory

Let order of element $a$ be $m$, then prove that order of $a'$ ( inverse of $a$) is also $m$ in a group.
For proving this I used the fact-
Inverse of inverse element is again the same element.
$(a')'=a$,
then taking the power $-m$ to both sides for m in set of positive integers, 
we get
$((a')')^{-m} =a^{-m}$ ,
implies that $(a')^m=(a^m)^{-1}$,
implies that 
= $e^{-1}$
= $e$
we get the proof finally. I think the proof is not systematic. Need systematic proof.

Comment: You have proved that $(a')^m = e$; why is $m$ the smallest integer such that that occurs?

Comment: Yes, so how should I improve my proof?

Comment: Prove what I told you: you have proves that $m$ is such that $(a')^m = e$, but that does not prove that $m$ is the order of $a'$, it could be another integer (smaller than $m$) with the same property. Prove this cannot happen and so $m$ will be the order of $a'$ too.

Comment: If I would have known how to show this I would have not asked the question. But then, thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Just prove that $(a')^m = (a^m)'$. Since $e$ is the only element whose inverse is $e$, this implies that the powers of $a$ which equal $e$ are the same as the powers of $a'$ which equal $e'=e$.

Comment: But, still i am not getting how to just prove it?

Comment: Notice that $(a')^{n+1} a^{n+1} = (a')^n a^n$ and complete the proof by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Heres the answer to my question:-
Let n be the order of the element a and m be the order of its inverse a^-1.
Claim: n=m
We have O(a)=n

implying that
a^n=e

implying that
(a^n)^-1=e^-1

implying that
(a^-1)^n=e

implying that
O(a^-1) is less than or equal to n.

implying that

m is less than or equal to n...........(1)
Also O(a^-1)=m
implies that
(a^-1)^m= e

implies that
(a^m)^-1= e
implies that
a^m =e
implies that
O(a) is less than or equal to m
implies that
n is less than or equal to m........(2).

From (1) & (2), we get
m=n.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different take.

We have $\langle a \rangle = \{ a^n : n \in \mathbb Z \} = \{ a^{-n} : n \in \mathbb Z \} =  \{ (a^{-1})^n : n \in \mathbb Z \} = \langle a^{-1} \rangle$.

Therefore, $o(a) = |\langle a \rangle| = |\langle a^{-1} \rangle| = o(a^{-1})$.